# dplyr mutate using character vector of column names

Tags: r, dplyr

data is a data.frame containing: date, a, b, c, d columns. Last 4 is numeric

```
Y.columns <- c("a")
X.columns <- c("b","c","d")
```

what i need:

```
data.mutated <- data %>% 
  mutate(Y = a, X = b+c+d) %>%
  select(date,Y,X)
```

but i would like to pass mutate arguments from character vector,
i tried the following:

```
Y.string <- paste(Y.columns, collapse='+')

X.string <- paste(X.columns, collapse='+')

data.mutated <- data %>% 
  mutate(Y = UQ(Y.string), X = UQ(X.string)) %>%
  select(date,Y,X)
```

But it didn't work. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you unquoting `UQ` there?

Comment: Just use `mutate_(Y = Y.string, X = X.string)`.

Comment: That just did the trick :) thanks

Comment: @AndreyKolyadin `mutate_` has now deprecated, check my answer for a more up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 3):

To use tidyeval with `UQ`, you need to first parse your expressions to a quosure with `parse_quosure` from `rlang` (Using `mtcars` as example, since OP's question is not reproducible):

```
Y.columns <- c("cyl")
X.columns <- c("disp","hp","drat")

Y.string <- paste(Y.columns, collapse='+')

X.string <- paste(X.columns, collapse='+')

library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(Y = UQ(parse_quosure(Y.string)), 
         X = UQ(parse_quosure(X.string))) %>%
  select(Y,X)
```

or with `!!`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(Y = !!parse_quosure(Y.string), 
         X = !!parse_quosure(X.string)) %>%
  select(Y,X)
```

**Result:**

```
   Y      X
1  6 273.90
2  6 273.90
3  4 204.85
4  6 371.08
5  8 538.15
6  6 332.76
7  8 608.21
8  4 212.39
9  4 239.72
10 6 294.52
...
```

**Note:**

`mutate_` has now deprecated, so I think tidyeval with `quosure`'s and `UQ` is the new way to go.

Comment: Well that's what Hadley Wickham says... but honestly it's so complicated, while the whole interest of dplyr is that it's so simple and intuitive... so far the only benefit I've found in (partially) understanding this new way of doing things is to understand some answers on stack overflow.