# Using dplyr verbs in a function with column labels as character vectors

Tags: r, dplyr, scope, rlang

I would like to create a function that takes a data frame and a character vector containing column names as input, and uses tidy verse quoting functions inside in a safe manner.

I believe I have a working example of what I want to do. I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution or I am thinking about this problem incorrectly (perhaps I shouldn't want to do this?). From what I can tell, in order to avoid variable scoping issues I need to wrap the column names in .data[[]] and make it an expression before unquoting for tidy verse NSE verbs.

Regarding previous questions  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203252/dplyr-mutate-using-character-vector-of-column-names) answer is along the right lines but I want to abstract the code into a function. A github [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2662)
 asks about this but using rlang::syms won't work as far as I can tell because the
 combination of the column labels with .data makes it an expression not a symbol.
 [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739871/correct-usage-of-dplyrselect-in-dplyr-0-7-0-selecting-columns-using-characte)
  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062213/dplyr-using-column-names-as-function-arguments)
 solve the problem but as far as I can tell don't account for a subtle bug in which the variables can leak
 in from the environment if they don't exist as column labels in the dataframe or the solutions don't work for the input being a vector of labels.

```r
# Setup
suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library("dplyr")))
suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library("rlang")))

# define iris with and without Sepal.Width column
iris <- tibble::as_tibble(iris)
df_with_missing <- iris %>% select(-Sepal.Width)
# This should not be findable by my function
Sepal.Width <- iris$Sepal.Width * -1

################
# Now lets try a function for which we programmatically define the column labels
programmatic_mutate_y <- function(df, col_names, safe = FALSE) {
  # Add .data[[]] to the col_names to make evalutation safer
  col_exprs <- rlang::parse_exprs(
    purrr::map_chr(
      col_names,
      ~ glue::glue(stringr::str_c('.data[["{.x}"]]'))
    )
  )

  output <- dplyr::mutate(df, product = purrr::pmap_dbl(list(!!!col_exprs), ~ prod(...)))
  output
}
################
# The desired output
testthat::expect_error(programmatic_mutate_y(df_with_missing, c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length")))
programmatic_mutate_y(iris, c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length"))
#> # A tibble: 150 x 6
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species product
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa     17.8
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa     14.7
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa     15.0
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa     14.3
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa     18  
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa     21.1
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa     15.6
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa     17  
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa     12.8
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa     15.2
#> # … with 140 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making things complicated. With the `_at` variant, you can use strings as arguments in almost every `dplyr` functions. `purrr::pmap_dbl()` is used to map calculation by rows.

```
programmatic_mutate_y_v1 <- function(df, col_names, safe = FALSE) {
    df["product"] <- purrr::pmap_dbl(dplyr::select_at(df,col_names),prod)
    return(df)
}

programmatic_mutate_y_v1(iris, c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length"))
```

```
# A tibble: 150 x 6
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species product
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa     17.8
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa     14.7
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa     15.0
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa     14.3
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa     18  
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa     21.1
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa     15.6
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa     17  
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa     12.8
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa     15.2
# ... with 140 more rows
```

Comment: That is certainly more elegant. Thank you. The '_at' variant usage is nice and I guess if one wants it as part of a series of piped expressions you could use something like `df %>% 
    mutate(product = purrr::pmap_dbl(dplyr::select_at(.,col_names),prod))`. I also like the implicit passing of '...'. Much tidier.

Answer (score 0):

We can turn `col_names` into a single expression with `parse_expr` and `paste`, then unquote when being evaluated in `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

programmatic_mutate_y <- function(df, col_names){
  mutate(df, product = !!parse_expr(paste(col_names, collapse = "*")))
}
```

**Output:**

```
> parse_expr(paste(c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length"), collapse = "*"))
Sepal.Width * Sepal.Length

> programmatic_mutate_y(df_with_missing, c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length"))
> Error: object 'Sepal.Width' not found 

> programmatic_mutate_y(iris, c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length"))
# A tibble: 150 x 6
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species product
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa     17.8
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa     14.7
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa     15.0
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa     14.3
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa     18  
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa     21.1
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa     15.6
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa     17  
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa     12.8
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa     15.2
# ... with 140 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A nice usage of parse_expr. This answer has the bug I mentioned though. If you define `Sepal.
Width` as an environment variable (with a length of the data frame row count, or 1) it is used in the computation and no error is raised.

Comment: To clarify, by environment variable I mean a parent environment in the call stack that can be found during evaluation of the expression.